# Custom Sorting with JQuery datatables

Tags: datatables

I want to sort data through Jquery datatable in particular column. Requirement is,  records to be displayed with data as "NA" first and then other records to be displayed by Ascending order. For example:

Current Order:
"A"
"B"
"NA"
"D"
"NA"

Result:
"NA"
"NA"
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [enum](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/enum) plugin should work:

```
$.fn.dataTable.enum( [ 'NA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ] );
$('#example').DataTable();
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/mukafrbk/).