# Implementing custom sorting for Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Setting up a self updating leaderboard for me and my friends, I opted to use a scraper+cronjob to feed .csv to an updating html table using this project.

### https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table

I want to combine two columns data with their respective data to be more useful when sorted from ascending to decreasing.

Example input.csv

```
Name,Rank,LP,Wins,Losses,Winratio

name1,Gold 5,10 LP,7W,5L,Win Ratio 58%

name2,Platinum 1,100 LP,15W,13L,Win Ratio 54%

name3,Platinum 3,44 LP,9W,6L,Win Ratio 60%

name4,Diamond 3,41 LP,148W,147L,Win Ratio 50%

name5,Master,79 LP,121W,97L,Win Ratio 56%
```

Example output:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N07DG.png)

Now, what I'm looking to do is make the "Rank", "Wins" and "Losses" columns to sort by highest

These are the ranks Highest to Lowest, I don't think I can just match the exact name specifically since everything below Diamond gets separated into five separate sub categories by adding a number behind the rank, the only exclusions to this are Master and Challenger.

Trying this code didn't seem to do the job previously

```
case 'Challenger':    return 1;
case 'Master': return 2;
case 'Diamond':   return 3;
case 'Platinum':   return 4;
case 'Gold':   return 5;
case 'Silver':   return 6;
case 'Bronze':   return 7;
```

I was able to find documentation to resolve an issue similar to mine on the datatables website but I'm not proficient enough in jQuery to adapt it to my situation.
https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_manual.html

Comment: We need a bit more information I think. Why didn't your switch work? It seems like it would help sort your ranks. Asuming you were removing the numbers and space after the ranks?

Comment: Can you post more code please

Comment: Post a snippet of the code you attempted for the sorting to get additional help.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886779/custom-sorting-with-jquery-datatables/48902964#48902964 and follow the link to the `enum` plugin - should do what you need.